# Laplace Transform using t-shift

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}cos(πt), & 1\leq t < 4 \\ 0, &elsewhere \end{cases}$$

Okay, I attempted to write it in terms of step functions and I got

$$ f(t) = cos(πt)u(t-1)-cos(πt)u(t-4)$$

But Now I'm not sure how to get the $$cos(πt)$$ for both parts in terms of (t-1) and (t-4) so then I could use the t-shift theorem. Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $$\mathcal L(g(t)u(t-a)) = e^{-as}\mathcal L(g(t+a)),$$ where $\mathcal L$ is the Laplace transform. This is probably the version of the 't-shift' theorem you want to use here.

Comment: How do I represent cos(πt) as the g(t+a) or whatever.

Comment: Just write $g(t) = \cos(\pi t)$ and then apply the formula.